# Explaination for what tensorflow.keras.dataset.minst.load_data() returns

Tags: python, tensorflow, tuples, mnist

I came across the statement:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

and its corresponding explanation for what it returns:

> **Returns: 2 tuples: x_train, x_test: uint8 array of grayscale image data with shape (num_samples, 28, 28). y_train, y_test: uint8 array of digit labels (integers in range 0-9) with shape (num_samples,).**

My doubt here is that whether `x_train`, `x_test`, `y_train` or `y_test` is itself a tuple that holds the values `(num_sample, 28, 28)` and `(num_sample)` respectively? and the tuple `x_train, x_test` is actually a tuple of tuple ?

I am new to this topic, so I am sorry if I am asking very silly questions! If anyone out there has an explanation for this, please write back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the shapes of those objects:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

print(np.shape(x_train))
print(np.shape(x_test))
print(np.shape(y_train))
print(np.shape(x_test))
```

> (60000, 28, 28)
>
> (10000, 28, 28)
>
> (60000,)
>
> (10000,)

You x_* datasets contain respectively 60000 and 10000 matrices of 28*28 pixels encoded as ints between 0 and 255.

Your y_* dataset contain the labels of what number is represented in your corresponding 28*28 pixels matrices.

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/mnist/load_data):

> `tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data`
>
> **Returns**:
>   Tuple of Numpy arrays: `(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)`.

But this wording is kind of confusing, the actual return type of the function is a tuple of two tuples with two numpy arrays each:

`Tuple[Tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray], Tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]]`